# Выборка по ключу из словаря списков

Tags: python, dict

Есть словарь который выглядит примерно в таком виде

```
spisok = { Meta-data:[{"User-Agent":"blablblablablabla"}], 

"collector":[
{
"id":"6863962924566809861",
"text":"let’s see #fyp #foryou #trump2020 #trump #america",
"createTime":1598140914,
"name":"Инфа по первому видео",
},

"videoUrl":"Ссылка для просмотра первого видео",
"hashtags":"теги первого видео",

{
"id":"32534277336586498674",
"text":"hahahahahahah",
"createTime":35215213521,
"name":"Инфа по второму видео",
},
"videoUrl":"Ссылка для просмотра второго видео",
"hashtags":"теги второго видео",

{
"id":"643560937538210912709",
"text":"sdjfgpod[agpadsopgfd",
"createTime":4365424354,
"name":"Инфа по третьему видео",
},
"videoUrl":"Ссылка для просмотра третьего видео",
"hashtags":"теги третьего видео"

]}
```

Как мне из этого словаря выводить через цикл к примеру то что находится в переменной videoUrl?

т. е. как-то так:

```
for x in videoUrl:
     print(x)
```

буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: Это не список, а словарь. Со словарями работать надо через ключи

Comment: ясно понятно, а как вывести то

Comment: Вы пробовали сами создать переменную `spisok`, используя код из вопроса??

Comment: не, типа я вообще ничего не записываю, есть кароче паблик апи - tik.fail/api/tiktok/v1/hashtag/mom после hashtag/ идет название хештега после чего апи возвращает всю инфу по найденным видео с этим хештегом

Comment: мне нужно чтобы оно из этого массива данных выводило циклом ссылки на видео

Answer (score 1):

```
for dict_ in spisok["collector"]:
    print(dict_["videoUrl"])
```

Comment: не пашет не пашет не пашет не пашет

Comment: ща я эдитну в другом виде

Comment: Что именно не пашет?

Comment: не выводит ничего абсолютно при выводе пустота

Comment: оно выводило как-то так смари  spisok["collector"][0]["videoUrl"]

Comment: но при цикле for x in spisok["collector"][0]["videoUrl"]: pritnt(x)

Comment: оно выводило ссылку по буквам т.е h

Comment: t t p s : / / v m 1 6

Comment: У меня пашет...

Comment: Походу он входные данные не так записал

Comment: не, типа я вообще ничего не записываю, есть кароче паблик апи - https://tik.fail/api/tiktok/v1/hashtag/mom после hashtag/ идет название хештега после чего апи возвращает всю инфу по найденным видео с этим хештегом

Comment: мне нужно чтобы оно из этого массива данных выводило циклом ссылки на видео